# setfocus on the msg display

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

ok the thing is that when i click delete on the view list page i want to set focus on the acknowledgment displayed there . delete is a ajax link . how would i do that?

Answer (score 2):

[Set focus on on ASP.NET MVC model errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725604/set-focus-on-on-asp-net-mvc-model-errors)

This will help you..

Comment: worked fine for me on button click but what to do on a link click?