# How to move focus to first error field with MVC client validation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I use MicrosoftMvcValidation.js for client side validation. Error messages show correct. However, my page is kind of long and when the error shows, it does not automatically scroll up to show the 1st error message or set focus to error field. How can I show a message beside button like "Error happens. Please correct your input", but without list of field errors; or automatically move focus to 1st error field?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have validation error, client-side validation will add `input-validation-error` class to those input boxes that caused validation. For example, in MVC3 if you have unobtrusive validation enabled you will get additional javascript files added to your file, like

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This means that you can use your own jQuery functions after these lines that would detect whether input-validation-error exists or not. This piece of code is something that I am using in my applications:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form[action*='New/']").submit(function () {
        var firstError = $(this).children(":first has('.input-validation-error')");

        if (firstError != null) {
            firstError.focus();

            return false; // no form posting
        }
    });
});
```

Replace the `form[action*='New/']` with your form action, e.g. `form[action*='/MyController/MyRegistrationAction/']` (`*=` means find this text at any location).

Comment: Your code is returning: `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: :first has('.input-validation-error')` with jQuery 1.8.3. This code on the other hand works: http://stackoverflow.com/a/726402/114029

Comment: It's should be: var firstError = $('.input-validation-error:first').get(0);

Comment: this is working only after it fails validation a second time. The first time validation fails, the error messages display, however the input does not get focus