# Prevent MVC 3 validation setting focus on the invalid field.

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation

I am using MVC 3 unobtrusive validation. When validation fires it sets the focus on the first invalid control.  How do i stop it doing this, i am more used to web forms and the equivalent would be to set the `SetFocusOnError=false` on the validation control.

Comment: Hello @Ben, check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475175/how-to-move-focus-to-first-error-field-with-mvc-client-validation

Comment: I have seen that already, that's the exact opposite of what i want, i want the validation NOT to set the focus on the invalid field, at the moment it does.

Comment: @BenRobinson have you solved this problem? I have similar requirements.

Answer (score 8):

Try setting a global option:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ 
    focusInvalid: false
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work, the focus still goes to the first invalid field, although it does look like the right setting now i have tracked down the relevant documentation. The puzzling thing is that if i hack the script to make the default for focusInvalid to be false it works.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not able to test at the moment, but I remember it being similar to this:

```
var settings = $.data($('form')[0], 'validator').settings;
settings.focusInvalid= false;
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work but i don't think it is a million miles off because when i had a look through the non minified version of the jq validator script i found a section that set some defaults the was setting `focusInvalid: true`. Changing it to false prevents the behavior but i would prefer to set it programatically in my view because i don't necessarily want it false for the entire app.

Comment: Try this: var settings = $.data($('form')[0], 'validator').settings;
settings.focusInvalid= false;

Comment: I just wrote a long rambling answer and realised you'd beat me to it. The reason this works is [explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487139/how-can-i-customize-the-unobtrusive-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3-to-match-my-styl)

Comment: You can also access the data more elegantly using `var validator = $('#formselector).data('validator');`