# How do you find the div that contains a input field with validation error using MVC validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, asp.net-mvc-validation

I have a mobile version of a website that has multiple "pages".  These five pages are all in one view made up of divs that are hidden/shown as they progress from one to another.

So when you first open the site, div1 is visable and div2, div3, etc. are hidden.  When you click the next button on div1, it hides div1 and makes div2 visible.  I am using MVC validation that occurs when the submit button is clicked.  The validation is simple: a field is required to have a value.  This works fine on the active(visible) div, but if the div is hidden (the error occurred on a previous page), the validation doesn't work.

How can I find out the div of the text field that is causing the problem?  What I'd want is to be able to click submit on div3 and if the validation failed on div2 (for example), I would like to make div2 visible again.

Here is a brief setup of my view.

```
<div id="div1>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)<br />
    <span id="ValidBuyerName">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)</span>
    <input type="button" id="btn_next1" value="Next &raquo;" />
</div>
<div id="div2>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address)<br />
    <span id="ValidBuyerAddress">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Address) </span>
    <input type="button" id="btn_next2" value="Next &raquo;" />
</div>
<div id="div2>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Phone)<br />
    <span id="ValidBuyerPhone">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Phone)</span>
    <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Save" name="Save" />
</div>
```

Here's a (crude) graphical example of what I want it to do:

```
--------------------------------
|                              |
|    | Name |                  |
|                              |
|    | Next |                  |
--------------------------------
```

Clicking next shows

```
--------------------------------
|                              |
|    | Address |               |
|                              |
|    | Next |                  |
--------------------------------
```

Clicking next shows

```
--------------------------------
|                              |
|    | Phone |                 |
|                              |
|    | Save |                  |
--------------------------------
```

If Address is blank, clicking save shows

```
--------------------------------
|                              |
|    | Address |               |
|    Address is required       |
|    | Next |                  |
--------------------------------
```

What is happening instead is that the page is allowed to be submitted with a blank address (because that div is hidden).

Just to clarify, I already have the validation set.  It works on the non-mobile version of the page where all of the divs are visible.  So I don't need to know how set validation.  What I need to know is how to find out which field has a validation issue so I can make it visible and the error will appear.

I found a good piece of code here:
[How to move focus to first error field with MVC client validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475175/how-to-move-focus-to-first-error-field-with-mvc-client-validation)
from @husein-roncevic, but it only works if the field causing the validation issue is already showing.  I tried to use the basic idea to show the field name or its parent div, but I couldn't figure out how to do that.  I think this may be a good starting point, I'm just not sure of the syntax to show the field name or its parent div.  Maybe someone could help me with that?

Below is additional code.  Not sure if this is helpful, but I'm trying to anticipate what others might want to see to help with this project.

Here's how I show and hide the divs when clicking the next button:

```
$("#btn_next1").click(function () {
        $("#div1").css({ "display": "none" });
        $("#div2").fadeIn(1000);
        return status;
});
```

Here's how the validation is set in the model:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is required")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
```

Let me know if I can provide any additional information.  I wrote I lot here, but the basic question is how to find what div contains the input throwing a validation error.

Comment: why don't you do the validation on `click` of `next` itself!! Just a line of suggestion..

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, Guruprasad Rao.  How do I trigger the MVC validation on a button click instead of on a submit?

Comment: I am hoping that you are creating a form in each view! Correct me if I am wrong! and if you post all the view code here or create **[MVCFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CsMvc)** to describe your problem in more detailed way then it would be much helpful to solve this!

Comment: There's only one view with multiple divs.  The view code is quite lengthy as there are a lot of divs.  The question is how do I identify the div that an error occurred in.  I don't think the full code would be needed to provide this answer.  I like your idea of validating on each click of next.  Is there a way to trigger the MVC validation without submitting the entire view?

Comment: You might then need to wrap your each div view in a `form` and then validate it on button click!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok!! So I've created this sample **[DOT NET FIDDLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZX7dp5)** for you to show how it can be done:

Just add the below function in your js for `.next` click

```
$(function(){
    $('.submit').click(function(){
            if($('form').valid()) {//This is what validates your model
                    var step=$(this).data('value');
                    var nextStep=step.split(/(\d)/)[0]+(parseInt(step.split(/(\d)/)[1])+1);
                    if(step!=='step3')
                    {
                        $('.'+step).toggle('slow');
                        $('.'+nextStep).toggle('fast');
                        $(this).data('value',nextStep);
                        if(nextStep==='step3')
                        {
                            $(this).text('Submit');
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert('you can submit form here! because all validations are done');
                    }
            }
            else {
                closeAlert();
            }
    });
});
```

Imaginary HTML:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
        <div class="form-group step1">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new {@class="form-control"}) 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="form-group step2">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Address)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address, new {@class="form-control"}) 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address)
        </div>
        <div class="form-group step3">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Phone)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Phone, new {@class="form-control"}) 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone)
        </div>
        <button type="button" data-value="step1" class="btn btn-success submit">Next</button>
}
```

Some CSS to make `divs` `hide` and `show`

```
.step1{
        display:block;
}
.step2, .step3{
        display:none;
}
```

> **I hope rest of the codes are self-explanatory and fiddle will help to**
>   **understand the same**